# How to define class-specific << operator in C++

Tags: c++

Given a class such as:

```
class Person
{
private:
    char *name;

public:
    Person()
    {
        name = new char[20];
    }
    ~Person()
    {
        delete [] name;
    }
}
```

I want to print to print the name from an instance of this, using a statement like the following:

```
cout << myPerson << endl;
```

What do I need to do to define the `<<` output operator for this class?

Comment: @aJ:            Spot on!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add this in the class:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Person& P);
```

and then define the operator<< something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Person& P) {
    out << P.name;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I'd advice to add getName() and remove friend operator.

Comment: Yeah, it IS quite peculiar to have a private, accessor-less data member which can only be accessed through << tricks!

Comment: @lupital, you need friend if you want to keep name private and otherwise unaccessible, as operator<< obviously does need to access it (and can't be a member function of Person because its left argument needs to be an ostream&).

Comment: I'm not sure ostream can be const either. I might be wrong on this.

Comment: Actually I'm certain of this.

Comment: Stream operators declared friend is a very common pattern, and a good one too. Exposing private members through get/set accessors for the sole purpose of streaming is bad, because it exposes the said accessors to everyone. A friend streaming operator at least restricts the access to the clear context of reading from and writing to stream.

Comment: Oops :( I apologise, ostream cannot be const. It's fixed now.

Comment: Yes but in this case I'm quite certain some other class would want to know the name of the person.

Comment: That's what I am talking about. Without getName() people will start to use << to obtain Person name by parsing stringstream.

Comment: No, the correct way is to use friend for this.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.8  If somebody misuses << to get the name, that's their mistake.

Comment: BTW, the friend declaration still has const on the stream parameter.

Comment: So I need friend or not?
I am confused!

Comment: I still don't agree that you need friend for it. If you in the future might need to have some other internal data printed out which is not exposed to other parts of the program it might matter. Otherwise it really doesn't.
And if that need eventually arises I'm still doubtful. What kind of data should be hidden to other code but visible in print outs? The only thing I can come up with is debug info.

Comment: operator<< has an excellent reason to access the private data of the class.  In fact, it would be a member of the class if it were possible - so it should definitely be a friend.  That's what friend is for.

Answer (score 3):

Define a member function print() that takes an ostream as an argument. Then let the overloaded operator<< call this member function. This way you can avoid using friend. Example:

```
void YourClass::print(ostream& out) const
{
    //implement printing ...
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const YourClass& m)
{
    m.print(out);
    return out;
}
```